# Probability of Appliance Functioning

Tags: probability

Suppose that an appliance is constructed in such a way that it requires that n independent electronic components are all functioning.  Assume that the lifespan of each of these, Tj , is an exponential random variable with parameter λj.

a) Let X be the random variable giving the lifespan of the appliance.  Find the CDF and PDF for X.

b) Find  the  expected  value  of X.   Then  find  the median lifespan  of  the  appliance  (that  is,  the  time t at  which  half  of  the  appliances  are  likely  to  have  broken  and  half  to  be  working).   Which  will  the manufacturer of the appliance use in advertising?

For part a) I found that the probability of a component working at time t is simply  λ*e^(- x* λ), the pdf. Since the appliance must have all components functioning and they are independent, I figured the probability of the appliance functioning at time t is ( λ*e^(-x λ))^n. I'm not sure this is right however - for part b I used the PDF I found from a) to find that E(X) =  (λ^(n-2))/n^2, but the median turned out to be the natural log of a negative number. Not sure where in the process I am going wrong..

Answer (score 1):

Your work on a is not complete.  The pdf for one component is fine.  When you raise it to the $n^{th}$ power the integral is no longer $1$, so you need to rescale.  The integral is $\frac {\lambda^{n-1}}n$ so the pdf becomes $n\lambda e^{-n \lambda t}$.  Integrate that to get the cdf as $1-e^{-n \lambda t}$.  The median comes when the cdf is $\frac 12$

Comment: The function I computed starts at λ^n, not 1, correct?

Comment: Yes, I had confused myself.  Corrected.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, can you elaborate? When I integrate (  λ*e^(-x λ))^n I get -e^(- λnt)* λ^(n-1)/n

Comment: That is correct.  That makes the integral from $0$ to $\infty$ be $\frac {\lambda^{n-1}}n$ so you need to multiply by $\frac n{\lambda^{n-1}}$ so the integral is $1$, giving my value.